# Tap Event not working insde a Swipe card Xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using the swipe card in the Xamarin form.
The Problem is i am unable to execute the tap event inside the card.

This is my Xaml code --

```
<swipecards:CardStackView 
    Grid.Row="0"  
    x:Name="CardStackView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cards[0]}" 
    Swiped="CardStackView_Swiped" 
    StartedDragging="CardStackView_dragged" 
    Margin="20" 
    BackgroundColor="#E0E0E0" 
    Focused="CardStackView_Focused">

    <swipecards:CardStackView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1">            
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .FullJobName}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}"/>

                    <Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Image 
                            x:Name="MyImage" 
                            Source="{Binding .CompanyProfImg}" 
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            Aspect="AspectFit" />

                        <ActivityIndicator 
                            BindingContext="{x:Reference MyImage}" 
                            IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}}"/>

                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .LocationName}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                        Style="{StaticResource label_med}"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .TotalSalary }" 
                        Style="{StaticResource label_med}"/>

                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Label 
                        Text="Comapny Name" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .CompanyName}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                        Style="{StaticResource label_med}"/>

                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Label 
                        Text="Key Skills" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .Skills}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                        Style="{StaticResource label_med}"/>

                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Label 
                        Text="Job Description" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding .Description}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                        Style="{StaticResource label_med}"/>

                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <BoxView Color="#DCDCDC" HeightRequest="2" />
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding .Postedby}" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                            Style="{StaticResource label_med}"/>

                        <Image x:Name="More_Option" Source="more.png">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding TapCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="Image1"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </swipecards:CardStackView.ItemTemplate>
</swipecards:CardStackView>
```

and ViewModel looks like this--

```
private ICommand tapCommand;
public ICommand TapCommand
{
    get { return tapCommand; }
    set
    {
        OnTapped(this.tapCommand);
    }
}
void OnTapped(object s)
{

}
```

what is wrong with my code?I have also tried the normal approach the normal tap event.but that was not also working.
i am refering this link -- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap)

Thank you guys.

Comment: is the More_Option image showing? are you sure you're clicking on the image?

Comment: yes..it's showing.
yeah..i have also tried this with a button..same result

Comment: where's the TapCommand defined? show us the code of the whole VM

Comment: This is my VM code-
`private ICommand tapCommand;

        public JobInfo()
        {
            tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);
        }

        public ICommand TapCommand
        {
            get { return tapCommand; }
            set
            {
                OnTapped(this.tapCommand);
            }
        }
        void OnTapped(object s)
        {

        }`

Comment: I mean the whole code of class which istance is "Cards[0]"